# `No such file or directory` when running a c# executable in linux from within another C# executable

Tags: c#, .net-core

**I am trying the following:**

1) Running a c# executable from another executable.

*I am using .net core 3.1*

**Problem**

- I get the following error when I run the app in linux.

```
Error =>No such file or directory    
 Exception encountered => System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (2): No such file or directory
  at System.Diagnostics.Process.ForkAndExecProcess(String filename, String[] argv, String[] envp, String cwd, Boolean
  redirectStdin, Boolean redirectStdout, Boolean redirectStderr, Boolean
  setCredentials, UInt32 userId, UInt32 groupId, UInt32[] groups, Int32&
  stdinFd, Int32& stdoutFd, Int32& stderrFd, Boolean usesTerminal,
  Boolean throwOnNoExec)
         at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartCore(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
         at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
         at ConsoleMQTT_Sender.ProcessClass.LaunchProcess(....) in ...
```

The app is generated through jenkins running in a linux environment.

The file is present but getting the above error.

Is this a cross-platform issue?
or a permission issue?

**Flag when running the first executable**

- dotnet firstexecutable.dll --secondexecutablepath "/opt/publish/xyz.dll"
- dotnet firstexecutable.dll --secondexecutablepath "dotnet /opt/publish/xyz.dll"

both giving the same exception

**How I am triggering the executable inside c# console app :**

```
            process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            process.OutputDataReceived += new System.Diagnostics.DataReceivedEventHandler(process_OutputDataReceived);
            process.ErrorDataReceived += new System.Diagnostics.DataReceivedEventHandler(process_ErrorDataReceived);

            process.StartInfo.FileName = firstexecutablepath;

                process.StartInfo.Arguments = "--secondexecutablepath \"" + executablepath + "\"";
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

            process.Start();
            process.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: How did you run it?

Comment: running  the dll files with arguments in a linux server @PavelAnikhouski

Comment: But you question is about executable. Please, share your code. Did you use shell execute?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski oops, sorry, have not out the code, skipped my mind. will edit the question now

Comment: Have you tried to specify the `WorkingDirectory` for process?

Comment: This is also happening to me - it works in a container when the host is Windows, but not in a container when the host is ubuntu. As you can see from https://github.com/aaronpowell/dotnet-delice/blob/master/src/DotNetDelice.Licensing/DotNetCli.fs, WorkingDirectory is set to System.Environment.CurrentDirectory.

Comment: for me it was a first a wrong path being considered in linux and then it was a permission error. The binary did not have permission and hence could not access it